# Margin auto without pushing away neighbour elements

Tags: html, css, width, margin

I have a *previous* button on the left and a *next* button on the right to a *h2* tag. I want the h2 tag to be `width: 20%;` and have `margin: auto;` to center it. The problem is that it pushes away the buttons to the left and the right, but I want them to be right next to the text. So theoretical I want the buttons to be inside of the margin of the h2 tag without being in the same div. Do you have any ideas to solve this?

My solution:
If the neighbour elements arent something to interact with you can give them the style `margin: -x%;` and just replace x with a number that fits the best for you. In my case it would have been 40% to get the buttons directly next to the text.
The problem was that you couldnt click the left button anymore, because he was inside of the margin of the text and so I finally moved the buttons inside one div together with the text what wasnt exactly what I wanted, but it works and thats better than nothing for now.

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no code or Image of what you're trying to achieve so I have to just assume what it could look like. Something that I understand by now is you want a button an h2 tag and a button so assuming that this is what you want I guess you can try tapping into the `position` property you can read about it here at [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-positioning-elements/) or [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) or [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) or can try `display: flex` you can read about it here [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-flex-property/) or [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) or here at [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) or can try `floating` it and can read about it here at [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-float-property-in-css/) or [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) or [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I already tried all these things. The best solution was to set the margin-right for the left button on -30% and the margin-left for the right button on -30% (this sort of reverses the margin: auto of the text). Now the only problem is that the left button cant be clicked, because it is inside of the margin of the text. I will share my solution if I found a working one.

Comment: I'm glad you found some lead but I think it would be a little easier for anyone who is answering your question if he gets to see your code or the desired design picture so I just wanna suggest that in the future it would be easier for people to answer your queries if you'll attach any of those or both of them. Have a nice coding journey ahead.